# Unable to specify Field Name C# for Checkobox field in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce

In Salesforce, I'm using a developer account and I'm trying to create checkbox with field label C# but it will not allow me to provide C# for the field name.it takes the value 'C'

If I'm to specify C Programming language it will create confusion as to C and C# both has same field name

How to resolve this issue. Im newbie to salesforce

Answer (score 2):

Salesforce field names do not allow special characters or spaces. See reference here:
http://kell.screenstepslive.com/s/knowledgebase/m/16056/l/338929-how-to-change-standard-field-labels

You can call it "C_Sharp" or something similar to tell it apart. Note that the field name is an internal reference for formulas and API access, NOT what the users see on the page (that's field label, and it does allow special chars).